# How do I publish calendar events from browser to calendar app on Android?

Tags: android, http, calendar, icalendar

I have a web service that emits calendar events: http://calevent.herokuapp.com. On iOS, that URL will open a calendar popup with event details and a button allowing the user to add to her calendar. On my main Android device, a Galaxy SIII running Android 4.1, it triggers a normal file download. The desired behaviour would be akin to that of iOS.

The service sets two important headers:

- `Content-Type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8`
- `Content-Disposition: inline; filename="event.ics"`

I've decoded the manifest of my device's calendar app, "S Planner". It does not define any `BROWSABLE` intent filters for `text/calendar` data. What it does define is some Google Calendar-specific stuff that I'm not sure if I can (ab)use.

Here's from the vanilla [Calendar app](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Calendar.git/+/master/AndroidManifest.xml):

```
<activity android:name="GoogleCalendarUriIntentFilter" android:label="@string/app_label"
   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"
   android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">

   <intent-filter
      android:priority="50">
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
      <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.google.com" android:pathPrefix="/calendar/event" />
      <data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.google.com" android:pathPrefix="/calendar/event" />
      <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.google.com" android:pathPattern="/calendar/hosted/.*/event" />
      <data android:scheme="https" android:host="www.google.com" android:pathPattern="/calendar/hosted/.*/event" />
   </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Is this a dead end? Are there other solutions that won't impact the user experience?

Answer (score 0):

**Issue:**

As far as I know, `Google` provides `Calendar` application as open source and the device manufacturers like `Samsung,Htc,Sony` are used to `modify or publish their own application` by replacing the default one while building their respective `Android source` codes.

So there are 2 possibilities:
Either `Google` has not added such feature in default app or `Samsung` has removed that feature by modifying the source.

In short, it is difficult or may be impossible to achieve this task.

When I had faced this issue , I had applied following solution.

**Solution:**

You can show calendar like user-interface in your application and represent events in it.

For creating such interface you can use 3rd party libraries if you wish.

First of all read that `event.ics` file programmatically and extract its data.
Then by using 3rd party libraries like [Caldroid](https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid) , you can represent events on particular dates in it.

I hope it will be helpful !!

Comment: Thanks. I actually need to store the event data in the user's calendar (for reminders and such) though - and I can't add any code that runs outside of the browser. I since looked up the vanilla source and I'm at least glad to say that Samsung did no such stupid thing ;).